# Hive TimeStamp column with TimeZone

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a created a table in hive with one column as timestamp datatype. While I am inserting into the hive getting different than the existing.

My column expected value : 2021-11-03 16:57:10.842 UTC (This I am getting as string). How I can store the above output in hive table( column with  Datatype as timestamp)

Comment: Can you please present your code with existing input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cast to convert this to timestamp after removing the word UTC. Since hive doesnt care about timezone intentionally, and display data in UTC, you should be in good shape.

```
select cast( substr('2021-11-03 16:57:10.84 UTC',1,23)  as timestamp) as ts
```

Pls note you need to have the data in above yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SS format.
Also pls note you can not use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(string_col , 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS'))` because we will loose millisecond part.

Comment: @Koshik My Question is that , Can we load any  timestamp column with timezone suffixed in the hive table.

Comment: SUSPENSION_START_TS: 1592247846685, function i used - date_format(concat_ws('.',from_unixtime(cast(STG.SUSPENSION_START_TS/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),cast(floor(STG.SUSPENSION_START_TS % 1000) as STRING)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z') SUSPENSION_START_TS,date_format(concat_ws('.',from_unixtime(cast(STG.SUSPENSION_START_TS/1000 as BIGINT),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),cast(floor(STG.SUSPENSION_START_TS % 1000) as STRING)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') SUSPENSION_START_TS1

Comment: I can see fundamental issue... If you have seconds, you can not calculate milliseconds. Milliseconds will be always 0. So, when you do `floor(STG.SUSPENSION_START_TS % 1000)`, it will always return 0 milliseconds.